# ODBC SQL update Statement issue if more than 32,000 characters

Tags: php, sql, string, odbc, sql-update

Here is the problem:  I have one giant string of xml data stored in a (BLOB)field in a table.  It holds some strings 70k characters or more at times.  I pull it out using an ODBC_Connection.

I can import (no problem).
I can manipulate the XML and save it back as a string (no problem).
I can save the string back into a mySQL field (no problem).

The problem comes when i try to save it back to its original field that i pulled it from.  If I save the string with less than 32,000 characters, we are golden.  If there are more than that many characters in the string, BAM.  I get this error message.

```
( ! ) Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error: [DataDirect][ODBC InterBase
driver][InterBase]Dynamic SQL Error, SQL error code = -104, token size exceeds limit,
SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in ...\Test\index4.php on line 129 Call Stack

#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0011  482872  {main}( )   ..\index4.php:0
2   0.1260  1033760 odbc_exec ( )   ..\index4.php:129
```

Here is the PHP code i am using just in case:

```
// Now save it back to the system
$conn=odbc_connect($DBNAME_O,$DBUSER_O,$DBPW_O);
if (!$conn)
{exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}
echo $tempFileXML;
$sql="UPDATE EHR_VISITS SET RECORD='$tempFileXML' WHERE EHR_VISITS_ID='1396'";
//  echo $theData;
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
odbc_close($conn);
```

Thanks for the help...

UPDATE:  This is connected to an interbase database, not MS SQL.   Also, I tried using a different ODBC driver, and got the same message but with a slightly higher character tolerance:  42000 instead of 37000.

HELP please....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried passing the data in as a parameter ?

E.g:

```
$sql = UPDATE EHR_VISITS SET RECORD=? WHERE EHR_VISITS_ID='1396'; 
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, $sql); 
$rs = odbc_execute($stmt, $tempFileXML);
```

Comment: I have tried this as well with the same result.  THANK YOU so much for trying to help.   I have posted some additional info above that I have tried.  I'm still stuck.

Comment: Have you also tried using the PHP ibase extensions ? see:http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ibase.php

Comment: THANKS KEVIN.  Your original advice was on the right track.  I've posted the answer which was based on your hint.  Thanks a million!