# Binding PHP variables to ODBC SQL UPDATE statement

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I am trying to bind parameters to an UPDATE statement using ODBC in PHP but the SQL statement is failing and I cannot for the life of me work out why. I've tried Googling but there seems to be very little info regarding using ODBC with PHP as opposed to the likes of MySQLi and PDO.

Most examples I've found with parameter binding use a SELECT statement but as far as I can tell that shouldn't make a difference. The closest answer I've found was [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742455/odbc-sql-update-statement-issue-if-more-than-32-000-characters). As far as I can see they are doing what I'm doing but I keep getting an error. Here is my code:

```
$updQuery = "UPDATE Demographic SET dmg_FirstName=? WHERE dmg_ID=?";
$update = odbc_prepare($connect, $updQuery);

$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$pID = 145100007;
$updResult = odbc_execute($update, array($fname, $pID)) or die (odbc_errormsg());
```

Here's the error I keep getting on the above code:

```
Warning: odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] SQL data type out of range, SQL state S1004 in SQLBindParameter in C:\xampp\htdocs\work\ajaxdd.php on line 44
```

The code works when I remove the parameter binding so if worst comes to the worst I can try to sanitise the data as best I can but that's obviously not preferable.

Comment: Looking up that error message [here](http://odbc.net/api/index.shtml?SQLGetTypeInfo), it looks as though this might be a bug in the ODBC driver you are using (it looks as if the data *type* identifier PHP is using is being rejected, rather than your actual value). ODBC prepared statements are very limited in this respect, in that everything is bound as a string. Ideally you would use a PHP API/driver for your specific RDBMS - is this not possible?

Comment: Unfortunately this does appear to be the case. I have to connect to a 4D SQL server which does have a PHP driver but it's years out of date, appears to be abandoned and I cannot actually find a driver that will work with recent PHP versions.

Comment: Can you try with PDO ODBC? http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php

Comment: I've just been checking out the PHP source for this operation, and it looks like it must be a bug with the driver. The data it doesn't like is fetched into the `sqltype` variable [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/odbc/php_odbc.c#1296) and it's used either [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/odbc/php_odbc.c#1357) or about 10 lines below - but it's never manually reassigned anywhere, the value comes from the driver and is sent unmodified back to the driver. Using ODBC may be you best option if there's no native driver, but try and find an updated version of the ODBC driver.

Comment: @DaveRandom Thanks for your help in solving this, I've been puzzling over it for some time now and it's nice to know the problem is at least not on my end!

Comment: [This document](ftp://ftp.4d.com/ACI_PRODUCT_REFERENCE_LIBRARY/Bug_Fix_Lists/Version_12/v12.5/Fixed_Bugs_ODBC_Driver_12.5.pdf) references a couple of bugfixes in the ODBC driver, one of them specifically related to PHP (although it doesn't look like the same problem, it does look as though the use of 4D from PHP via ODBC should at least *work* if you have an up to date driver)

Comment: Were you able to get anything working with this? I find myself in the same boat of having to hit a 4D database from PHP. With their 64bit ODBC driver I can connect via PDO, but it bombs out on preparing the statement. Using strictly ODBC I can execute a query, but I can't bind any parameters. I get the same error as you.

Comment: @Matt Yeah I'm afraid I simply had to settle for strictly using ODBC with no bound parameters or other modernities. Not nice but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

This probably means that you're trying to insert an ID that is higher than that integer column allows. Try verifying if this is the case first. What is the type of `dmg_ID`? 145100007 is a rather high number so I suspect this might be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for responding but unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the culprit. It's a LONG INT so the length shouldn't be an issue. As a test though I removed the ID and got it to update by another string field instead but got the same error.